# Me sale como resultado 0 y las variables están en flotante

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    float op, acum;
    acum=1;
    op=1;
    i=1;
    printf("Ingrese un numero entero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
           op=(1/i)/(1/i+1);
            acum=op*acum;
            i++;
        }
        printf("El resultado de la serie es: %.10f ",acum);

}
```

Pienso que el problema está en la operacion op= divisiones y eso pero no se cómo arreglarlo
El ejercicio trata de hacer la siguiente secuencia ((1/1)/(1/2))x((1/3)*(1/N)) no se bien si me explico

Comment: Lo unico que tienes que devolver es el resultado de toda esa secuencia?

Comment: Recomiento la lectura de [esta](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integer-Division.html) página. División entre enteros siempre da un entero, división entre flotantes (o que al menos 1 sea flotante) resulta en un flotante.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo del calculo que quieres hacer y pon el resultado final obtenido

Comment: Si, lo unico que debe devolver es el resultado de la secuencia

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya pude corregir el código y agregar ciertas condiciones. Ya pude hacerlo comprobar las respuestas y de paso pude aprender algo gracias a ustedes. Disculpen las molestias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que cambiar el tipo de dato pues la división entre enteros siempre da un entero. En tu código `1` e `i` son ambos enteros, por lo que la división será un entero también. Para más información puedes consultar el [manual de libc GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integer-Division.html).

Respecto al código, solo hay que hacer estos cambios:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    float op, acum;
    acum=1;
    op=1;
    i=1;
    printf("Ingrese un numero entero: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
           op=(1.0/i)/(1.0f/i+1);
            acum=op*acum;
            i++;
        }
        printf("El resultado de la serie es: %.10f ",acum);

}
```

Escribir `1.0` "convierte" el `1` (entero `int`) a `1.0` (flotante `double`).

Por otro lado, `1.0f` "convierte" el `1` (entero `int`) a `1.0` (flotante `float`).

Con esos cambios la división será flotante también puesto que al menos uno (el numerador) de los argumentos de división en `(1.0/i)` y `(1.0f/i+1)` (los paréntesis están bien?) es un flotante.

Mientras que la división de ambos resultados también será flotante pues ambos, numerador y denominador, son flotantes.

Comment: Me parece que el calculo de la secuencia no esta bien

Comment: @Japv concuerdo, tampoco sé si esté bien, probablemente hacen falta paréntesis en `i+1`, pero supongo que el problema por el que pregunta está relacionado a la división con enteros.

Comment: Hay que esperar a que ponga un ejemplo con numeros para que uno pueda verificar el resultado

Comment: Por ejemplo seria que ingrese un n=6 y seria ->> ((1/1)/(1/2))*((1/3)/(1/4))*((1/5)/(1/6)) y me devuelva solo el resultado de este

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya pude corregir el código y agregar ciertas condiciones. Ya pude hacerlo comprobar las respuestas y de paso pude aprender algo gracias a ustedes. Disculpen las molestias.